# How to display images from url asynchronously in scrollview?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Hi i'm new to iPhone application.In my application i used tableview. when i click table cell it does to detail view which has tab bar controller.i have 3 tabbaritems. one to display description, another one to display 5 images in scrollview and third one to display location. when i click table cell it takes more time to load all images. please i need help to complete my application.Many people said to do asynchronously but i don't know how to do. thanks in advance. waiting for a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Load the images in function loadImage and call it in background as follows...So your view will appear and images will be loaded in background

```
     [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(loadImag) withObject:nil];
```

Comment: this answer is very helpful to complete my app

Answer (score 2):

You can use GCD to load those images asynchronously

I don't know how is the layout of your viewcontrollers but you should put in the viewDidLoad of your ViewController which displays the images something like this.

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = 
              dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
dispatch_async(queue, ^{
  theImageView.image = // Whatever your method to grab the image will be
});
```